# jenkins pipeline - how to set ChoiceType Condition options

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've two deployment categories, namely install and upgrade with the following code below
and in the next parameters using Active choice reactive parameters called "services" i want to create separate ChoiceType which if the Category "Install" the choiceType: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT' (which means we can choose more than one service ) and if the Category "Upgrade" the choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', is that possible?

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
        description: 'Select Deployment Type', 
        filterLength: 1, filterable: false, 
        name: 'deployment', 
        script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', fallbackScript: 
                                         [classpath: [], 
                                         sandbox: false, 
                                         script: "return['error']"], 
                                         script: [classpath: [], sandbox: false, 
                                            script: "return['Install','Upgrade']"]]],
```

something like this

```
if (deployment.equals("Install"))
{
[$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT',
...
...
}
if (deployment.equals("Upgrade"))
{
[$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
        choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
...
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't conditionally create the parameters with different attributes, however there is a simple solution for your need: You can define an **Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter** and set the choice type to **Formatted HTML**, in the HTML define a select with a `multiple` attribute that will be defined according to your deployment parameter.
The groovy script for the `services` parameter will look like the following:

```
return """
<select name="value" ${deployment.equals("Install") ? 'multiple' : ''}>
   <option value="Service1">Service1</option>
   <option value="Service2">Service2</option>
   <option value="Service3">Service3</option>
   <option value="Service4">Service4</option>
   <option value="Service5">Service5</option>
</select>
"""
```

Now when `deployment` value will be set to  *Install* the select will be a multi select, and for other values it will be a single select.
You can of course create the `options` section dynamically using groovy code.
Also important to know that the values that will be passed to your job are the option values (`value="XXX"`) not the option text itself.

Pipeline script will look like:

```
    properties([ 
        parameters([
                [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
                 choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
                 name: 'services', 
                 omitValueField: false, 
                 referencedParameters: 'deployment', 
                 script: [$class: 'GroovyScript', script: [sandbox: false, script: '''
                        return """
                        <select name="value" ${deployment.equals("Install") ? "multiple" : ""}>
                           <option value="Service1">Service1</option>
                           <option value="Service2">Service2</option>
                           <option value="Service3">Service3</option>
                           <option value="Service4">Service4</option>
                           <option value="Service5">Service5</option>
                        </select>
                        """''']]]
        ]) 
])
```

UI config will look like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFxRO.png)

##### Update

Example for setting the options dynamically - if you want to set the options according to another parameter, lets say `branch` you just need to add it to the *Referenced parameters* of your `deployment` parameter and add the relevant logic according to the value of the parameter.
Here is an example for the new groovy script:

```
services = ['Service1','Service2']
if(branch =='master'){.   // create any logic you need acodring to the brach value
     services = ['Service3','Service4']
}
options = services.collect{"<option value='${it}'>${it}</option>"}.join('\n')
return "<select name='value' ${deployment.equals('Install') ? 'multiple' : ''}>${options}</select>"
```

Comment: thanks @noam for the answer, but could i ask again, if i added additional active choice parameter called "branch" with the following value : "feature-1" , "feature-2" and in the Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter we want to add additional condition if the feature-1 then we can add additional <option value=service-feature-1> and if the feature-2 then we can add additional <option value=service-feature-2> ?

Comment: @fahri i will add this info to the answer

Comment: thanks @noam, but i just tested using the following command above "Test"  seems not working, is there something missing?

Comment: In your test example use: `options = servicename.collect{"<option value='${it}'>${it}</option>"}.join('\n')` or alternatively use a parameter in the closure:  `options = servicename.collect{s -> "<option value='${s}'>${s}</option>"}.join('\n')`

Comment: both options dont seem to work which only appear like this when click build with parameter 
`services {}`
even i try to define the following variable first 
`def servicename
def options
int it`

Comment: Start from a freestyle  project with the example i provided, make sure it works and then work your way to what your want to achieve.